# Want to make sure that the Big O notation i got is correct

Tags: java

I have written this code but I have to find the big O notation. I came up with O(n2) but I am not sure if it is correct. Please somebody help. Thanks

```
int n = array.length;

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  int c = 1;
  for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
    if (array[i]==array[j])
      c=c+1;
    if (c>(array.length/2)){
      return array[i];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: based on nested for loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, this is an O(n^2) operation because the number of operations you do is proportionate to the square of the number of data elements in your input array.

The fact that you have a "bailout" condition if the number of matches exceeds half of the length of the array also does not change the cardinality of the operation, it's still an N-squared operation since that is the limiting behavior of the function.

One way you can verify this is through Monte Carlo simulation:

1. Start with N=2, increase it up to N= say 100
2. Add a second counter inside your inner loop to let you know how many times you hit the inner code block
3. Create a randomized array of length N having only binary (1/0) values
4. Run your function and keep track of the number of times you hit the inner loop
5. For each choice of N, run the simulation say 100 times and average your results for each choice of N
6. Plot the average iteration count versus N on a log-log scale.
7. A best-fit line having a slope of 2 on the log-log graph indicates that the operation is O(N^2).  A slope of 1 would mean that it's O(N).  A slope of 3 would indicate O(N^3).

Answer (score 0):

If we assume no 2 equal elements in array it will be equal to Worst Case Bubble Sort which equals O(N2). You may see sample sort in [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Sorting/Bubble_sort)

And also information on cost of Bubble sort might found [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/big-oh/bigoh.html).